# Nginx remove a get parameter from URL

Tags: nginx

In NGINX how can I redirect any URL that contains ?SID=(insert long string of numbers/letters)

To a clean URL that is exactly the same but without this query?  Other get query must remain untouched.

Also I only want to perform this redirect if the URL also does not contain '/sgps/'

Any takers?